# Amazon Batch Job won't terminate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two Amazon Batch Jobs stuck in Running state due to bad code.The jobs will not terminate. I have tried using the terminate button on the developer console and also have used the command line interface.

This is the command I have used:

```
$ aws batch terminate-job --job-id [My job id inserted here ] --reason "Failed"
```

The command doesn't throw any errors but the job is still running in cloud watch. What can I do to force it to stop/terminate?

Answer (score 0):

Ssh into corresponding EC2 instance, check running docker containers, find appropriate one, kill it.